# I am trying to get g_total when user enters tax. so far its not returning any value. i had tried this thing so far

Tags: jquery, html

my blade

```
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td><b>Total</b></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control total" readonly></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td><b>Sales Tax</b></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="tax" class="form-control tax" ></td>
           </tr>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td style="border:none"></td>
           <td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="g_total" class="form-control g_total" readonly></td>
```

and I am using jquery as

```
$('tbody').delegate('.qty,.price,.dis,.tax','keyup',function(){
    var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
    var qty =tr.find('.qty').val();
    var price =tr.find('.price').val();
    var dis =tr.find('.dis').val();
    var amount =(qty * price)- (qty * price * dis)/100;
    tr.find('.amount').val(amount);
    total();
    var tax =tr.find('.tax').val(); 
    var g_total =total() + (total() * tax)/100;
    tr.find('.g_total').val(g_total);
});
```

For tax and g_total i am using this method.

```
$('tfoot').delegate('.tax','keyup',function(){
    var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
    total();
    var tax =tr.find('.tax').val(); 
    var g_total =total()+ (total * tax)/100;
});
```

Total Function i am using this method.

```
//--------------------For total----------
function total()
{
    var total=0;
    $('.amount').each(function(i,e){
        var amount = $(this).val()-0;
        total+=amount;
    })
    $('.total').val(total);
};
```

I am getting all the values right except g_total. Nothing appears for variable g_total

Comment: You seem to have g_total used at two places, 1 - control id, 2 - variable name.  I hope that is not causing you issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the result of your function:

```
var g_total = total() + (total * tax) / 100;
```

But your function doesn't return anything.  It looks like you meant to return the calculated value:

```
function total()
{
    var total=0;
    $('.amount').each(function(i,e){
        var amount = $(this).val()-0;
        total+=amount;
    })
    $('.total').val(total);
    return total; // <---- here
};
```

---

As an aside, you're also calling the function twice, which is wasteful:

```
total();
var tax = tr.find('.tax').val(); 
var g_total = total() + (total() * tax) / 100;
```

Instead, store the result in a variable and re-use the result:

```
var calculatedTotal = total();
var tax = tr.find('.tax').val(); 
var g_total = calculatedTotal + (calculatedTotal * tax) / 100;
```

(Note that it's not 100% clear which of your variables/functions etc. are intentional, typos, etc.  Overall the code is very difficult to follow, and calling *everything* "total" doesn't help.  But hopefully you at least get the idea of storing the result in a variable so as to not re-calculate it over and over.)